# Broken eslint for Linux command `eslint`

Tags: development

Once upon a time, I wanted to write an app. I learned about common practices, it lead me to more and more discoveries. Out of the blue, I found about `lint`, which means beauty code patterns. In my app, which attends by the name `backend-app`, tastes `javascript` and has `node-js` spices, I discovered the command `eslint src/ --fix`. I thought I would live happily ever after, but the villain `error log` appeared and crushed me to tears.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'optionator'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/bin/eslint.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/bin/eslint.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was some conflict with `apt` installed package.

1. Run command `sudo apt remove '*eslint*' --dry-run`;
2. Run command `sudo apt remove '*eslint*'`;
3. Go to project folder;
4. Remove folder `node_modules` and file `package-lock.json`;
5. Run command `npm i`
6. Run command `eslint --fix`